# TRUNCATE mysql table several databases

Tags: php, mysql

i need to clean several tables in several databases before try the submits

```
$db_server = include('root.php');
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$sqla = "TRUNCATE TABLE `info`.`2012_august`";
$sqlb = "TRUNCATE TABLE `stu`.`2012_august`";
$sqlc = "TRUNCATE TABLE `stu`.`2012`";
if (@mysql_query($sqla))
    {
    echo ("success"."</br>");
    }
else
{
    echo ("un success".mysql_error()."</br>");
     }
```

only the first table clears its data.how can i solve this.

Comment: Very basic debugging would have solved this for you. -1 and voting to close as too localised.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: i'm a basic learner still .Thank you vary much for help..

Comment: @sadpcd Basic learners should stay away from `mysql_` functions even more. A beginner cannot write safe code with them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$a = array("TRUNCATE TABLE `info`.`2012_august`",   // create an array of queries
           "TRUNCATE TABLE `stu`.`2012_august`", 
           "TRUNCATE TABLE `stu`.`2012`");

foreach ($a as $value) {                            // iterate through array
    if (@mysql_query($value))
    {
        echo ("success"."</br>");
    } else {
        echo ("un success".mysql_error()."</br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you vary much for help..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Also, don't use the error suppression operator.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only executing `$sqla`.  You need to execute the others, or combine them into one separated by semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$sqla = "TRUNCATE TABLE `info`.`2012_august`";
$sqlb = "TRUNCATE TABLE `stu`.`2012_august`";
$sqlc = "TRUNCATE TABLE `stu`.`2012`";
```

values to be store.But you have used only `$sqla` to store.Thats why other values are not storing.`You have to store them all by using comma`or `by storing all the values into an array and call them at the time of store`.